# Typescript generator functions as paramter

Tags: typescript, generator

I have the following generator function

```
function* dispatchIncomingMessageImp(msg: string) {
  console.log(`dispatching incoming message = ${msg}`);
  yield put({ type: 'INCOMING_MESSAGE', messge: msg });
}
```

Now I'm passing this as a parameter to another function which has the following

```
function process(clientId: string, dispatchIncomingMessage: (msg: string) => void){
   dispatchIncomingMessage('test');
}
```

Now I'm calling process the following way

```
process('id1', dispatchIncomingMessageImp)
```

However the function `dispatchIncomingMessageImp` does not get invoked, if I remove the generator symbol then it works.

Comment: Once you call a generator function you get an iterator back and you need to interact with it in order for the body to be executed. Why are you passing a generator function if you don't treat it as one? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: the generator function is actually a redux-saga with a `put` command inside, hence the generator function.